# Multiple point-in-time-recoveries

Tags: postgresql

I'm sure this is a dumb question, but I'm wondering if somebody could please inform me of best practice here. I'm using patroni and pgbackrest for cluster management and backup, and in the case of somebody screwing something up I want them to be able to restore to a point in time. Then, if they don't like that restoration, to be able to re-restore to another point in time, e.g. 5 minutes in the future or the past.

The problem is, the first restore happens and then the database promotes and starts a new timeline. Now all of a sudden, the user has to figure out the old timeline id and enter that in to start moving around on that timeline. Is there a better way? E.g. after restoration the database stays in read-only mode until they get to the point they want and then they can certify and promote the database manually?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand the question correctly, but the second restore can specify

```
recovery_target_timeline = 'current'
```

to remain on the timeline that was active when recovery started.